# In a set of loops, why is only the first one being considered?

Tags: loops, vbscript, asp-classic, filesystemobject

This code is part of a function thats is being called several times.

```
for r = 0 to 4
    do until searchname.AtEndOfStream
        lineData = lcase(searchname.ReadLine())
        if instr(lineData,N(r))>0 then
            if (r = 0) then
                v = v + 1
            elseif (r = 1) then
                w = w + 1
            elseif (r = 2) then
                x = x + 1
            elseif (r = 3) then
                y = y + 1
            elseif (r = 4) then
                z = z + 1
            end if
        end if
    loop
next
```

My problem is that it only considers `r = 0`. I've tried `ubound(N)` instead. I've also tried replacing the `for (r = 0)` loop with five separate loops for `v`, `w`, `x`, `y` and `z`. I've tried several other methods and different formatting too, but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the `r = 0` case, when the inner loop has reached `searchname.AtEndOfStream` and you increment to the next value or `r`, *`searchname` is still at the end of the stream*. Therefore, the `do` loop only runs for the first case of the `for` loop. Consider this alternative:

```
do until searchname.AtEndOfStream
    lineData = lcase(searchname.ReadLine())
    for r = 0 to 4
        if instr(lineData,N(r))>0 then
            if (r = 0) then
                v = v + 1
            elseif (r = 1) then
                w = w + 1
            elseif (r = 2) then
                x = x + 1
            elseif (r = 3) then
                y = y + 1
            elseif (r = 4) then
                z = z + 1
            end if
        end if
    next
loop
```

By switching the loops around, you don't reach the end of the stream until you've finished iterating over both.

Comment: Thank's for getting back to me so soon.
Works perfectly. I wouldn't have picked up on it other wise.

Just wondering, if I ever do want to go by the other structure, how can I move the pointer back to the begining after the first loop?

Comment: Well what is `searchname`; what kind of structure, and how is it created? Have you looked in its documentation?

Comment: `searchname` is simply a textfile that's been opened. ( `set searchname = objFSO.OpenTextFile(("C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Files\"&idname), 1, true)` )

Comment: Use `ADODB.Stream` so you can use `.Position` property to reset the stream back to the starting position. Still use FSO to locate the file but then open it using the `ADODB.Stream` instead of the `TextStream` FSO object.

Comment: Also I wouldn't store files inside your `wwwroot` you should link them via a virtual directory so they are outside of the security model of the website.